# AdListener isn't a type

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following this official Flutter [tutorial](https://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0d_pbgeeG8)

I wrote the same code as in the video tutorial, but when I added the `AdListener` inside `AdState class`,  the `Android Studio` gave me an error: `the AdListener isn't a type`.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your guide, indeed, there is no AdListener type, but I was able to solve this problem, change the version of the google_mobile_ads package to the following and it will help:

```
google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0
```

Comment: with this version 0.11.0 android studio keep to show me the error but give me to add the google library, I add library and still getting the problem, please look at the picture: https://i.ibb.co/9HSFrh5/Sans-titre.jpg

Comment: So you didn’t click on the “Import” button, import the library and everything will work, maybe I didn’t understand you, in this case enter the command “flutter clean” into the console - re-download the packages, reinstall the application on the emulator, your IDE will rethink the connection and that’s it, it should work.

Comment: i follow all the steps in your comment and i get the same error: AdListener isn't a type
https://ibb.co/FXdwQdp

one thing, i use android studio dophin | 2021.3.1 Canary 7

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Code, but it doesn't matter, my advice is to find an up-to-date manual, because you had a problem with having a class, I found a solution, but you still have problems...

Comment: i solved the problem by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mJQQmjnL3Q

Comment: AdListener work only with google_mobile_ads: ^0.12.0 version